# I got Unknown column error on having with count

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In Laravel 6 I have a request of ads with related images count

```
$ads = Ad
    ->getByTitle($this->filter_title)
    ->onlyNoneInfo()
    ->getByStatus('A')
    //->imagesCount(true)
    ->getUserByStatus('A')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ads.creator_id')
    ->orderBy($this->order_by, $this->order_direction)

    ->select(
        'ads.*',
        'users.name as creator_username',
        'users.email as creator_email',
        'users.phone as creator_phone'
    )->addSelect(['ad_images_count' => AdImage
        ::selectRaw('count(*)')
        ->whereColumn('ad_images.ad_id', 'ads.id')
    ])

    ->offset($limit_start)
    ->take($ads_per_page)
    ->distinct()
    ->paginate($ads_per_page);
```

and I see `sql` request `ad_images_count` field:

```
   SELECT distinct `sda_ads`.*, `sda_users`.`name`     AS `creator_username`, `sda_users`.`email`     AS `creator_email`, `sda_users`.`phone`     AS `creator_phone`, (  SELECT count(*) 
    FROM `sda_ad_images` 
    WHERE `sda_ad_images`.`ad_id` = `sda_ads`.`id`)     AS `ad_images_count` 
    FROM `sda_ads` 
    LEFT JOIN `sda_users` on `sda_users`.`id` = `sda_ads`.`creator_id` 
    WHERE `ad_type` <> 'I'     AND `sda_ads`.`status` = 'A'     AND `sda_users`.`status` = 'A' 
    ORDER BY `price` asc limit 4 offset 0
```

and it works for me with valid value in `ad_images_count`.
I need to set filter to show only ads  with images and I added a scope in `App Model`  :

```
public function scopeImagesCount($query, bool $check_images_count)
{
    if ($check_images_count) {
        return $query->where('ad_images_count', '>', 0);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

But if to uncoment line in the request :

```
//->imagesCount(true)
```

I got error :

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**
With request in which I commented ad_images_count subquery:

```
$ads = Ad
    ::getByTitle($this->filter_title)
    ->onlyNoneInfo()
    ->getByStatus('A')
    ->getUserByStatus('A')
    ->imagesCount(true)
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ads.creator_id')
    ->orderBy($this->order_by, $this->order_direction)

    ->select(
        'ads.*',
        'users.name as creator_username',
        'users.email as creator_email',
        'users.phone as creator_phone'
    )
    /*
    ->addSelect(['ad_images_count' => AdImage
        ::selectRaw('count(*)')
        ->whereColumn('ad_images.ad_id', 'ads.id')
    ])
    */
    ->offset($limit_start)
    ->take($ads_per_page)
    ->distinct()
    ->paginate($ads_per_page);
```

I modified scope with logging:

```
public function scopeImagesCount($query, bool $check_images_count)
    {
        \Log::info('scopeImagesCount $check_images_count ::');
        \Log::info($check_images_count);

        if ($check_images_count) {
            \Log::info('CHECKING  ::');
            return $query->select(['ad_images_count' => AdImage
                ::selectRaw('count(*)')
                ->whereColumn('ad_images.ad_id', 'ads.id')
            ])->where('ad_images_count', '>', 0);
        }
        \Log::info('SKIPPED CHECKING  ::');
        return $query;
    }
```

And I see logging and Unknown column error in log file:

```
[2020-01-30 11:29:59] local.INFO: scopeImagesCount $check_images_count ::  
[2020-01-30 11:29:59] local.INFO: 1  
[2020-01-30 11:29:59] local.INFO: CHECKING  ::  
[2020-01-30 11:29:59] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ad_images_count' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `sda_ads` left join `sda_users` on `sda_users`.`id` = `sda_ads`.`creator_id` where `ad_type` <> I and `sda_ads`.`status` = A and `sda_users`.`status` = A and `ad_images_count` > 0) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ad_images_count' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `sda_ads` left join `sda_users` on `sda_users`.`id` = `sda_ads`.`creator_id` where `ad_type` <> I and `sda_ads`.`status` = A and `sda_users`.`status` = A and `ad_images_count` > 0) at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/ads-backend-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669)
```

In resulting sql no subquery with ad_images_count
What is wrong?

**MODIFIED BLOCK # 2:**

If to comment imagesCount with request

```
        $ads = Ad
            ::getByTitle($this->filter_title)
            ->onlyNoneInfo()
            ->getByStatus('A')
            ->getUserByStatus('A')
//            ->imagesCount(true)
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ads.creator_id')
            ->orderBy($this->order_by, $this->order_direction)

            ->select(
                'ads.*',
                'users.name as creator_username',
                'users.email as creator_email',
                'users.phone as creator_phone'
            )
            ->addSelect(['ad_images_count' => AdImage
                ::selectRaw('count(*)')
                ->whereColumn('ad_images.ad_id', 'ads.id')
            ])

            ->offset($limit_start)
            ->take($ads_per_page)
            ->distinct()
            ->paginate($ads_per_page);
```

I see sql generated :

```
   SELECT distinct `sda_ads`.*, `sda_users`.`name`     AS `creator_username`, `sda_users`.`email`     AS `creator_email`, `sda_users`.`phone`     AS `creator_phone`, (  SELECT count(*) 
    FROM `sda_ad_images` 
    WHERE `sda_ad_images`.`ad_id` = `sda_ads`.`id`)     AS `ad_images_count` 
    FROM `sda_ads` 
    LEFT JOIN `sda_users` on `sda_users`.`id` = `sda_ads`.`creator_id` 
    WHERE `ad_type` <> 'I'     AND `sda_ads`.`status` = 'A'     AND `sda_users`.`status` = 'A' 
    ORDER BY `price` asc limit 4 offset 0
```

with ad_images_count field having valid value

If to uncomment imagesCount with scope:

```
    public function scopeImagesCount($query, bool $check_images_count)
    {
        \Log::info('scopeImagesCount $check_images_count ::');
        \Log::info($check_images_count);

        if ($check_images_count) {
            \Log::info('CHECKING  ::');
            return $query->select(['ad_images_count' => AdImage
//            return $query->addSelect(['ad_images_count' => AdImage
                ::selectRaw('count(*)')
                ->whereColumn('ad_images.ad_id', 'ads.id')
            ])->where('ad_images_count', '>', 0);
        }
        \Log::info('SKIPPED CHECKING  ::');
        return $query;
    }
```

I got error :

```
[2020-01-31 15:27:37] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ad_images_count' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `sda_ads` left join `sda_users` on `sda_users`.`id` = `sda_ads`.`creator_id` where `ad_type` <> I and `sda_ads`.`status` = A and `sda_users`.`status` = A and `ad_images_count` > 0) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ad_images_count' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `sda_ads` left join `sda_users` on `sda_users`.`id` = `sda_ads`.`creator_id` where `ad_type` <> I and `sda_ads`.`status` = A and `sda_users`.`status` = A and `ad_images_count` > 0) at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/ads-backend-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669)
```

I tried to use addSelect - the same error.
looks like in having must subquery repeated, but not column name. 
How?

**MODIFIED BLOCK # 3 :** 
I try to use having :

```
$prefix= DB::getTablePrefix();

$ads = Ad
    ::getByTitle($this->filter_title)
    ->onlyNoneInfo()
    ->getByStatus('A')
    ->getUserByStatus('A')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ads.creator_id')
    ->orderBy($this->order_by, $this->order_direction)

    ->select(
        'ads.*',
        'users.name as creator_username',
        'users.email as creator_email',
        'users.phone as creator_phone'
    )
    ->addSelect(['ad_images_count' => AdImage
        ::selectRaw('count(*)')
        ->whereColumn('ad_images.ad_id', 'ads.id')
    ])

    ->offset($limit_start)
    ->take($ads_per_page)


    ->havingRaw(' ( SELECT count(*) '.
        ' FROM `'.$prefix.'ad_images'.'` '.
        ' WHERE '.$prefix.'ad_images.ad_id = `'.$prefix.'ads`.`id` ) > ?', [0])
    ->paginate($ads_per_page)
```

but I got error :

```
Unknown column 'ads-backend-api.sda_ads.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: 
select count(*) as aggregate from `sda_ads` left join `sda_users` on `sda_users`.`id` = `sda_ads`.`creator_id` where `ad_type` <> I and `sda_ads`.`status` = A and `sda_users`.`status` = A having  ( SELECT count(*)  FROM `sda_ad_images`  WHERE sda_ad_images.ad_id = `sda_ads`.`id` ) > 0
```

Looks like  `sda_ads`.`id` is invalid condition. Which kind of wrapping does it need ?

I also tried without “`” symbol wrapping as :

```
->havingRaw(' ( SELECT count(*) '.
    ' FROM `'.$prefix.'ad_images'.'` '.
    ' WHERE '.$prefix.'ad_images.ad_id = '.$prefix.'ads.id ) > ?', [0])
```

and got :

```
Unknown column 'ads-backend-api.sda_ads.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `sda_ads` left join `sda_users` on `sda_users`.`id` = `sda_ads`.`creator_id` where `ad_type` <> I and `sda_ads`.`status` = A and `sda_users`.`status` = A having  ( SELECT count(*)  FROM `sda_ad_images`  WHERE sda_ad_images.ad_id = sda_ads.id ) > 0
```

In my database ads-backend-api I have sda_ads table with id field.

“sda_” is db prefix in database configuration.

Which way is right ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your scope you are directly requesting 'ad_image_count' alais but you have to make alias first like you did in raw query

```
    public function scopeImagesCount($query, bool $check_images_count)
    {
      if ($check_images_count) {
        return $query->select(['ad_images_count' => AdImage
            ::selectRaw('count(*)')
            ->whereColumn('ad_images.ad_id', 'ads.id')
        ])->where('ad_images.ad_images_count', '>', 0);
     }
     return $query;
   }
```

Comment: Please, take a look at MODIFIED BLOCK :

Comment: try ad_images.ad_images_count as the error shows you don't have the column name

Comment: Try to use addSelect method instead of select. Not sure if it'll work, but why not to try..

Comment: Please, take a look at MODIFIED BLOCK # 2

Comment: Please, take a look at MODIFIED BLOCK # 3